# How do I use Scrapy FormRequest to simulate next page link request on paginated .asp site

Tags: web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

I'm having trouble scraping this page: http://maps.kalkaskacounty.net/propertysearch.asp?PDBsearch=setdo

My scraper gets all of the links the sub pages and scrapes those correctly (25 results), but isn't correctly submitting the form request to get the next 25 results to scrape (and so on). I would appreciate any help anyone can offer. Thanks!

```
import scrapy

class ParcelScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'parcel_scraper'
    start_urls = ['http://maps.kalkaskacounty.net/propertysearch.asp?PDBsearch=setdo',
                  'http://maps.kalkaskacounty.net/,']


    def parse(self,response):
        for href in response.css('a.PDBlistlink::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_details)

    def next_group(self,response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'DBVpage':'next'},
            formname={'PDBquery'},
            callback=self.parse,
            )

    def parse_details(self,response):
        yield {
            'owner_name': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Owner Name")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'jurisdiction': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Jurisdiction")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'property_street': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Property Address")]/following::td[1]/div[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'property_csz': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Property Address")]/following::td[1]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
            'owner_street': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Owner Address")]/following::td[1]/div[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'owner_csz': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Owner Address")]/following::td[1]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
            'current_tax_value': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Current Taxable Value")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'school_district': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"School District")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'current_assess': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Current Assessment")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'current_sev': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Current S.E.V.")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'current_pre': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Current P.R.E.")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'prop_class': response.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Current Property Class")]/following::td[1]/text()').extract_first(),
            'tax_desc': response.xpath('//h3[contains(text(),"Tax Description")]/following::div/text()').extract_first()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, you never call "next_group" def class. You call "parse" and "parse_details" but fail to call back next_group.

This is where using meta tags could help you achieve what you are trying to do:
***Just an example; not resuing your code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class YourSpiderClassHere(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "..."
    allowed_domains = ["SomeSite.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://somesite.com/myScrappingSite']

    def parse(self, response):
        listings = response.xpath('//li[@class="result-row"]')
        for listing in listings:
            date = listing.xpath('.//*[@class="result-date"]/@datetime').extract_first()
            link = listing.xpath('.//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').extract_first()
            text = listing.xpath('.//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/text()').extract_first()

            yield scrapy.Request(link,
                                 callback=self.parse_listing,
                                 meta={'date': date,
                                       'link': link,
                                       'text': text})

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[text()="next > "]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url), callback=self.parse)

    def parse_listing(self, response):
        date = response.meta['date']
        link = response.meta['link']
        text = response.meta['text']

        compensation = response.xpath('//*[@class="attrgroup"]/span[1]/b/text()').extract_first()
        type = response.xpath('//*[@class="attrgroup"]/span[2]/b/text()').extract_first()
        address = response.xpath('//*[@id="postingbody"]/text()').extract()

        yield {'date': date,
               'link': link,
               'text': text,
               'compensation': compensation,
               'type': type,
               'address': address}
```

Comment: Thanks NeilR. I'll try updating my spider tonight with your suggestion.

Comment: I added this to my spider:    `next_page = response.css('div.ccrow div.cc2:nth-child(3) a.DBVpagelink::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)`   but it didn't return any additional results. The response.css('div.ccrow div.cc2:nth-child(3) a.DBVpagelink::attr(href)').extract_first() returns "javascript:document.PDBquery.DBVpage.value='next';document.PDBquery.submit();"  for the next page link - which is why I was asking about FormRequest